# How to export a state that can be used as a data provider component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I think this is a very basic question, but I want to know how to pass the state (Data) or export it by default.

In the below code I have some data array passed on to the setData. I want to make use of the Data in different pages. So I want to make the below code as a component which provides data array. I'm just confused should I to have the return.. or do I have to make it as a callback.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export default function FetchedData() {
    const [Data, setData] = useState([]);// I want the use the content inside Data in different pages

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () =>{
      const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products");
      setData(data);
    }
    fetchData();
    return () => {
      //
    }
  }, [])


}
```

Comment: I’m not sure “Data to be exported as a separate component” really makes sense, but from the sounds of what you want I think you’re after [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)? Is this the kind of behaviour you’re after?

Comment: I just want to use the content in  Data, ... in different pages. I don't know how to pass it or return it. I should export Data and should be able to import it in other pages.

Comment: Do you want it to persist across pages? So after has been data fetched, when you go to a page, that page already has it? Assuming you're using client-side routing, then, as Jordan suggests, using React Context could be a way to go. If what you want is a handy way of reusing the fetching functionality then you could just create and use a hook in the different pages.

Comment: Thank you ourmaninamsterdam, Robert & Jordan for your valuable time. I wanted to use the Data in different pages and I got the answer to it by referring to the React Custom Hook. One can export the state and use them as props.callback. A little confusing but its different from context.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Jordan Garvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6140521/jordan-garvey), it seems like what you're looking for is [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). There's not really any other way to "export" a state from one component. Functionality-wise, it essentially allows you to use a shared state throughout the component tree. You can use its values in any component, and you can change its values in any component as well. The implementation is a little complex, so check out the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to get answers for how to use it in your specific situation.